# How to use opencv cvKnearest class from delphi xe2

Tags: c++, delphi, class, function, reference

I am writing an image processing delphi program using opencv delphi (https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV) it has reference to most of function but cvKnearest . (a class containing some functions written in c++) 
how to reference to the functions?

Comment: You cannot directly consume C++ classes from Delphi. You'll need to write some wrapper code in C++ that exposes the functionality in flat C style functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See branch "Classes" in https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV
Examples:
* samples\Classes\CvKNearest\Class_2D_Point_Classification.dpr
* samples\Classes\CvKNearest\CvKNearest/Class_labKNN.dproj

Answer (score 0):

that class is recently added the complete link is 
https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV/tree/Classes/samples/Classes/CvKNearest